# Why FaceboxRender is not working?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, facebox

I've installed FaceboxRender and JQuery and Facebox. Following the instrutions on http://github.com/ihower/facebox_render/

I've tried Facebox alone, in my rails app and it's working.
After that I've put the folder facebox_render in vendor/plugins/facebox_render/, I added

```
include FaceboxRender
```

in /app/controllers/application.rb
restarted my app, then wrote the link:

```
facebox_link_to "Whatever", :url => whatever_path
```

but nothing happen when I click.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: any luck?  getting same problem...had some luck hacking it but the styling was wrong

Answer (score 2):

Have you included the facebox javascripts and css files in the head of your html layout?

```
<%= javascript_include_tag('jquery', 'facebox') %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('facebox') %>
```

Failing that, are you getting any javascript errors showing up in firebug?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I've included them:

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "jquery-ui", "map", "facebox", "faceplant" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery', 'jquery.validate', 'facebox', 'application'  %>
```

and in application.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
    loading_image : 'loading.gif',
    close_image   : 'closelabel.gif'
  }) 
})
```

when I click on:

```
   facebox_link_to "test", :url => '/test/new'
```

this is what and Firebug's console reports:

```
$("a[rel*=facebox]").facebox is not a function
anonymous(function())                   applicat...262613317 (line 4)
anonymous()                             jquery.j...260464452 (line 19)
anonymous([function(), function(), function(), 2 more...], function(), Object name=F)                                 jquery.j...260464452 (line 12)
anonymous()                             jquery.j...260464452 (line 19)
anonymous()                             jquery.j...260464452 (line 19)
[Break on this error] close_image : 'closelabel.gif'\n      applicat...262613317 (line 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you didn't linked JS file multiple times in your layout.